# Abelian Galois group and prime ideals

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/k$ be abelian extension with Galois group $G$. Let $p$ be prime of $k$, let $P$ be a prime of $K$ lying above $p$ and let $G_P$ be its decomposition group.

Let $E$ be the fixed field of $G_P$. Let
$$ G=\cup_{i-1}^r\sigma_i G_P$$
be a coset decomposition. Let $q=P\cap E$.

> How can I know that the primes $\sigma_i q$ are primes of $E$?

Here are what I thought.

Since $q$ is a prime in $E$, it follows that $\sigma_i q$ is a prime of $\sigma(E)$. Since $K/k$ is normal, $\sigma_i(E)=E$. So $\sigma_i$ is a prime in $E$. Is this correct? But, where did I need $G$ is abelian?

Comment: You don't know a priori that $\sigma_i(E) = E$. 

But since all the subgroups of $G$ are abelian, then ([by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory)) all the intermediate fields $E$ of $K/k$ are abelian extensions $K/E$

Comment: What is prime of k ?